# add text just before caption number of lstlistings

Tags: numbering, captions, lstlisting

How can I add a text (i.e., `#` symbol) just before the number (between label and number, i.e. `Listing #1:`) in **lstlisting caption**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could re-define `\thelstlisting`. Note that this has to be done after `\begin{document}` because it's not defined before that point in document. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\thelstlisting{\#\arabic{lstlisting}}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Test]
Put your code here.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Note that this will change references to lstlistings as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\thelstlisting{\#\arabic{lstlisting}}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Test,label=test]
Put your code here.
\end{lstlisting}
\ref{test}
\end{document}
```

will print `\ref{test}` as `#1`. If this is not what you want, you could use the/my `caption` package to re-define the caption label format (using `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat`) instead, i.e.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{with-number-sign}{#1~\##2}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{labelformat=with-number-sign}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Test,label=test]
Put your code here.
\end{lstlisting}
\ref{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and and great package. Your answer solves the issue but I rather prefer caption package. do you mind to expand the answer by including DeclareCaptionLabelFormat way?

Comment: @Sezen As requested I just added an example